# C# change file name on DOS wildcards

Tags: c#, vb.net, wildcard

We have a  .net program which essentially copies the files from one folder to another and , often, changes the files' names during the copying. The customer provide the file names to be copied & the target file names using DOS style wildcards.

For example:

Source: *.log  Target: *.txt

Copy aa.log to aa.txt  , bb2.1.log to bb2.1.txt  etc

or

Source: abc*.csv Target: KK*_123.csv

Copy abcxyz.csv to KKabcxyz_123.csv, abc1722.mm.csv to KKabc1722.mm_123.csv

How can I implement  such copying / renaming in C# or VB.net ?

`File.Copy(SourceFile, TargetFile )` doesn't support wildcards (*,?) in the file names, so probably the question is, how to generate the target file name ?

PS
If it's absolutely necessary I can enforce some limitations on the source / target file names, but I'd like to avoid it.

PPS
If necessary, the process can be divided to the separate parts. 
Example #2 : Source: abc*.csv Target: KK*_123.csv

could be replaced with
Source: abc*.csv Target: KK*.csv

and 
Source: KK*.csv Target: *_123.csv

.

Comment: If the source is abc*.csv and the target is xyz*_123.csv then should abcxyz.csv get copied to xyzxyz_123.csv instead of abcxyz_123.csv?

Comment: You are right. I fixed my question. Actually the expected target file name in this example should be xyzabcxyz_123.csv., i.e. it just adds 'xyz' to the beginning of the file name  and adds '_123' before file extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a completely built-in solution, but .NET will do pattern matching for you. [Directory.EnumerateFiles(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a pattern to match source files on. You could do something like

```
foreach (var sourceFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(myPath, thePattern))
{
    var targetFile = ApplyPattern(sourceFile, thePattern);
    File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile);
}
```

You would need to implement ApplyPattern yourself by examining the sourceFile found by EnumerateFiles and applying the placeholder logic.

Perhaps there is a better solution that I'm not aware of. If not, this at least will handle the source matching for you.